# Integration problem regarding trigonometric substitution

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I am not that experienced in calculus yet and therefore am a bit rough with some substitution concepts. I am facing a problem with the following integral

$$\int_0^a b \sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}} dx$$.

I tried substituting $x/a=\sin \theta$.

$b\int_0^{\pi/2} \sqrt{1-\sin^2\theta}dx$

$b\int_0^{\pi/2} \cos\theta dx$

$d\theta=a \cos\theta dx$, therefore

$b\int_0^{\pi/2}(1/a) d\theta$

$b/a(\pi/2-0)=b/a(\pi/2)$
which is actually not the answer given(The answer given is $(\pi\cdot a\cdot b)/4$)

I would like to know where i went wrong. (My suspicion is that if i substitute $x/a$ as $\sin\theta$ then the limits would change to $\pi a^2/4$ instead of $\pi/2$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x=a\sin\theta$, then $\mathrm dx=a\cos\theta\,\mathrm d\theta$, and your integral becomes$$\int_0^{\pi/2}b\sqrt{1-\sin^2\theta}a\cos\theta\,\mathrm d\theta=ab\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^2\theta\,\mathrm d\theta=\frac{\pi ab}4.$$I have no idea about how your $\cos\theta$ vanished.

Comment: Oh i just noticed that i had substitued dx=1/acostheta thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by José's answer, you forgot the differential. A faster way to solve the integral is the following:
$$y=b\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}} \implies \frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$$
The integral is equivalent to a quarter of the area of an ellipse:
$$\int_0^a b\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}}\mathrm dx=\frac14\pi ab $$